# CSS changes not appearing - Django

Tags: django, django-templates

When I make new changes to my css the new changes are not showing. If i delete a style it still shows and if I delete my `<link>` tag all the styles disappear. I can edit styles with inspect element but the same changes do not show if I edit my style sheet. This is strange because it shows old styles only.

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

**base.html**

```
 {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
```

Even if I delete my entire `static` directory it still loads the old styles.

Comment: is this in production or dev? is `DEBUG` set to `True`?

Comment: If production then you need to run `python manage.py collectstatic` if local then rerun `runserver` command

Comment: The project is in development. `runserver` did not fix it

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by clearing my browser cache